# Leveling joists for drywall installation

Tags: drywall, joists, level

So I asked a question a couple of days ago about leveling my ceiling joists. I got great recommendations, from strapping with 1X3 straps, and also metal studs.

So I placed String Lines across and found out I have a max of half an inch difference from one joist to another. There are actually 2 joists right next to each other that are lower than others by 0.5 inch (the third and 4th joist from the left in the picture).

So my question is: Will the imperfections be noticeable if I decide not to correct this before drywall placement? Thank you. [image]

Comment: Are those joists sloping at an angle (low side above the doors; high on opposite end)? If so, what is the difference at the high end?

Comment: Use drywall shims.

Comment: The low side is actually in the middle area. Right above the door, they are all level, I just put a 12 ft LVL beam across the door you see there, so all the joists are level there. All those 6 joists are supported by the beam I installed. But as you move away from that area, the two joists (3 and 4 from the left) have bowed down half an inch. At the other end, they again level out, no bowing.

Comment: I believe there is a kind of flooring that requires a very level, very horizontal subflooring.  I don't know if that might be relevant for your situation, but if so, you could call a flooring store and ask them for the specs.  They might say that horizontal to within half an inch is fine.

Comment: aparente001, this is for my ceiling joists, not floor joists. This is also a one story home, no floors above.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say, I find myself noticing every imperfection that I'm responsible for. I don't easily notice imperfections in other people's work unless I'm looking for them. It looks like your joists are on about 24's so 1/4 inch per foot dip in the middle might not be too noticeable as long as it's level'ish above the doors. The doors offer a reference to level, very close to the ceiling so they are the primary area of focus.

Keep in mind 1/4 inch per foot is plumbing drain slope.

I'd definitely go with 5/8 drywall especially if you on 24's and shim where necessary. And avoid drywall seams around the areas in question.

It boils down to who it's for. If it's your house and you can live with it, it's fine. If it's a customer you're going to have to consider what they'll think.

Try having a look at other ceilings in the house or a friend's house and see if you notice any dips and then check with the big straight bar.

Comment: Great advice Joe Fala, thanks. Yes I was thinking about 5/8 drywall. But didn't know about the seams around these joists. I will heed your advice. This is actually a house I just bought, remodeling it for myself. I will live in it. And yes they are 24 on center.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You could also try pulling the low joists up by laying a long peice of timber across the top of the joists and attaching the low joists to it and pulling it up. I'm not confident in that advice as I'm not a roofer and I don't have much experience with roofing but I would give it a try.

Comment: Oh I did sort of that today. The reason for the bowing, I found out, was actually the gusset plates (basically the plywood) on the truss joints got weaker (they were stapled) on those joists. This allowed the adjoining studs that connect inside the gusset plates to come apart and also bow down. What I did was, build a support wall, attempted to jack it up very gently to re-align the misaligned studs, clamped the gusset plates together, then screwed an 18 gauge plate onto the plates for extra support.

Comment: Sound like you know your framing and roofing much better than me! Are you going to be drywalling and taping? Drywall isn't to hard but taping is very difficult. I've gotten pretty good at it but even nearly perfect ceilings are a challenge.

Comment: Yes, that is my plan. I have lots of time to do the work. It's more like a weekend deal for me. If I do the drywall and screw it up, I guess I will find someone to take it down and do it over. But my plan is to do it myself. Thanks

Comment: Take your time with the mud. Check YouTube videos on how to tape. There are some really talented tapers on there. I was pretty decent at it, so I thought. I watch lots of videos and learned tons of tricks and methods to get a better result.

Comment: So, from your comment above about jacking, did you reduce some of the droop? If this was a kitchen, I'd fix it with cross strapping. (Cabinets are less forgiving.) I'd still be tempted to cross strap @16OC, but that's just because I don't like 2' spans in ceiling rock.

Comment: Yes it did reduce the droop. That is why I ended up with half an inch after my attempted repair. Now, I could have jacked it up more to align the adjoining studs inside the gusset plate. But I was just a little too scared pushing the limits. I was basically satisfied with the outcome.

Comment: @JoeFala The last paragraph in your answer is the most important. I'm doing a master bathroom remodel. I found the ceiling joists to be quite out of level relative to one another. Going by the book would have *major* repercussions. I was disheartened, but then I went around the house and found quite a few ceiling spots where the drywall is just not flat, and I've never noticed them. I'm still going to even out the joists a bit. It won't be perfect but at least as good as the rest of the house. I'm not likely to ever fix the problem spots created from before we bought the house.